# SED Showing CRLF While Vim Not Showing

Tags: vim, sed

Why `sed l\;q` shows a CRLF while opening the file in Vim with `:set list` doesn't show any CRLF

Answer (score 2):

If it is a well-formatted CRLF file, vim will recognize it as such and set `fileformat` to `dos`. Try it with `:set fileformat?`. Thus `set list` will interpret CRLF, correctly, as legitimate line endings for this file format.

See `:help fileformats` for more on file format auto detection. Also, [this tips page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/File_format) expands on this and for example how to convert between different file formats.